# Combine output of a completion handler function with a function that returns AnyPublisher of combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have two functions, first function gets data from a combine function. It is called as following:

```
self.programStorageProvider.fetchHealthPrograms()
```

above function has following signature:

```
func fetchHealthPrograms() -> AnyPublisher<[HealthProgram], Error>
```

Now I want to get some data from another function which itself gets data from a completion handler using above returned array([HealthProgram]), something like following:

```
private func updateHealthProgramStageStatus(healthPrograms: [HealthProgram]) -> AnyPublisher<VoucherIDs, Error> {
    Future { [weak self] promise in
        self.fetchProgramsStages { result in
            var updatedHealthPrograms = [HealthProgram]()
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let stagesList):
                for stage in stagesList {
                    // Perform some operation
                        updatedHealthPrograms.append(program)
                }
                let voucherIDsResult = VoucherIDs(all: updatedHealthPrograms, valid: [""])
                promise(.success(voucherIDsResult))
            case .failure(let error):
                promise(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

I want to use it like following:

```
public func getVoucherIDs() -> AnyPublisher<VoucherIDs, Error> {
    return self
        .programStorageProvider
        .fetchHealthPrograms()
        .map { programs in

            var healthProgramsWithVoucherId = programs.filter { $0.voucherId != nil }
            
            return self.updateHealthProgramStageStatus(healthPrograms: healthProgramsWithVoucherId)
            
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But in return line in above function I am getting following error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<VoucherIDs, any Error>' to return type 'VoucherIDs'

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `switchToLatest()` after your `map` in your `getVoucherIDs()` method.

```
public func getVoucherIDs() -> AnyPublisher<VoucherIDs, Error> {
   return self
       .programStorageProvider
       .fetchHealthPrograms()
       .map { programs in

           var healthProgramsWithVoucherId = programs.filter { $0.voucherId != nil }
        
           return self.updateHealthProgramStageStatus(healthPrograms: healthProgramsWithVoucherId)
        
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

}